# How do you copy/paste image data?

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

Using C++ and the WinAPI, how do I copy the image data from a pre-loaded image into the clipboard?

Comment: Use the raw Windows API clipboard functions, or use the OLE clipboard functionality, or for C++/CLI use the .NET clipboard functionality. In any case, RTFM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an object that implements [`IDataObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688421%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and then place it on the clipboard using [`OleSetClipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686623%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

When you place data in the clipboard you have the ability to specify multiple formats. This is so that the application reading the clipboard can enumerate the formats and decide which one to use.

There are quite a few ["*standard*" clipboard formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729168%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (with known constant values), e.g.:

- `CF_BITMAP`: A handle to a bitmap (HBITMAP).
- `CF_DIB`: A memory object containing a [BITMAPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183375%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure followed by the bitmap bits.
- `CF_DIBV5`: A memory object containing a [BITMAPV5HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183381%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure followed by the bitmap color space information and the bitmap bits.

You can also register custom formats using [`RegisterClipboardFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649049%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Office exposes images as a  number of different formats that they've registered, e.g.:

```
DWORD CF_PNG = RegisterClipboardFormat("PNG");
DWORD CF_JFIF = RegisterClipboardFormat("JFIF");
DWORD CF_GIF = RegisterClipboardFormat("GIF");
DWORD CF_ENHMETAFILE = RegisterClipboardFormat("CF_ENHMETAFILE");
DWORD CF_METAFILEPICT = RegisterClipboardFormat("CF_METAFILEPICT ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The EditCopy function on this page of MSDN gives a good example of what you want to achieve:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016(v=vs.85).aspx

You will need to change the data type from CF_TEXT to CF_BITMAP in order to tell windows it is of an bitmap mime type.